# WPF Disabled button's background

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

I tried to change `Button`'s style when it is disabled:

```
    <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="MyButton2">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="MediumAquamarine" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="MediumBlue" />
        
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DeepPink"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>

    </Style>
```

and my button:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource MyButton2}" Content="My text" Width="100" Height="30" IsEnabled="False" />
```

But for some reason this style is not applied to the button:

[image]

How can I apply this style to my button? And can I do it without overriding the button's template only with styles?

Comment: Please add the button's template as well.

Comment: my button has the default template. i didn't override it

Comment: Well it looks like you are never setting `IsEnabled` to `false` in the first place

Comment: the button's xaml is shown in the end of question. As you can see IsEnabled attribute is set to false

Comment: What OS/type of application are you creating? That button doesn't look like a default WPF button.

Comment: My OS is Windows 8.1 Enterprise

Answer (score 36, accepted):

> Can I do it without overriding button's template only with styles?

I think not, because the Controls in the Windows has a default `Styles` and `ControlTemplates` and *in each version of Windows they are different*. In addition, the styles - it's just a lot of settings, usually the style does not change/add behavior to control, which is responsible for this `ControlTemplate`.

`Note:` the Style it is a set of setters, for example: set the background, size, etc. The `ControlTemplate` is the form, in which all of these settings will appear.

In this situation, I recommend you all to change the ControlTemplate, where it is possible to have the same behavior aka view, regardless of the version of the system.

In this case, try this `Style`:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="MyButton2">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="MediumAquamarine" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="MediumBlue" />

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="MyContentPresenter" 
                                          Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                          HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                          VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DeepPink"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Button Content="Button" 
            IsEnabled="False"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            Width="75" 
            Style="{StaticResource MyButton2}"
            Click="Button_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 16):

The odd thing is that it "works" when i run it, well partly, and this is likely to the template of the button actually. Here is a buttons entire template.

```
<Style x:Key="FocusVisual">
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Rectangle Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Background" Color="#FFDDDDDD"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Border" Color="#FF707070"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Background" Color="#FFBEE6FD"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Border" Color="#FF3C7FB1"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Pressed.Background" Color="#FFC4E5F6"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Pressed.Border" Color="#FF2C628B"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Background" Color="#FFF4F4F4"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Border" Color="#FFADB2B5"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Foreground" Color="#FF838383"/>
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Background}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Border}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Pressed.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Pressed.Border}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Border}"/>
                        <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Foreground}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

As you can see there is alot of things going on in the control template of the button. In example the following SolidColorBrushes are used when the ctl is disabled.

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Background" Color="#FFF4F4F4"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Border" Color="#FFADB2B5"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Foreground" Color="#FF838383"/>
```

You can either change these (in scope of your usercontrol, app), or you can rewrite the control template as Suggested by Daniel Ward.

You may dump the default template of any control by right clicking it in the UI Editor, Edit Template -> Create a copy... Through blend, code or disassembling :)

Hope it helps!

Cheers

Stian

Comment: This should be marked as the answer as it doesn't remove the style of the button (e.g. hovered, pressed, etc)

Comment: Nice post. My **suggestion** for the **disabled trigger** `<Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">` is to use only this setter: `<Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5" />` Then you don't need to set 3 colours and especially buttons with **nested content** change its view. **Images** and nested text look like disabled by reducing the opacity.

Comment: Most helpful answer +1

Answer (score 10):

Might be late on this one but there is an in built property provided by WPF:

`IsHitTestVisible="False"`

Any kind of mouse movement is not detectable using the above on a control thus disabling a control without changing its actual look and feel.

Comment: this answer has nothing to do with the question. It is actually the opposite of what the person wants

Comment: Also this does not hold you from navigATating through the buttons via keyboard and tab. This might end in unexcepted behavior, if you rely on this solution.

Comment: it did the trick for me , thank you

Answer (score 6):

My solution is a bit easier but it does not allow to use a `Transparent` background color for a disabled button and you cannot change the `BorderBrush` either.
What I do is using a `TextBlock` as a content of the button and change the color of this `TextBlock` background when it's disabled.

My button is written like this:

```
<Button>
    <TextBlock Text="Click me!" Style="{StaticResource MyButtonContentStyle}" />
</Button>
```

And MyButtonContentStyle is written like this:

```
<Style x:Key="MyButtonContentStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

It worked like a charm for us.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the only way to do this is to remove the chrome theme from the button. **Note that this will remove the hovering/clicking animations, as well as the button's gradient on Windows 7, if you're building for that.**

Unfortunately, Microsoft decided that [disabling a button should give the background a hardcoded value from a private property in the chrome theme's code-behind](http://www.infosysblogs.com/microsoft/2010/07/wpf_-_disabled_look_for_button.html), which means that you can't change it through the XAML. That link describes the problem:

The control template for `Button` uses `ButtonChrome`, which has a private property called `ButtonOverlay`, which, when the `Button` has `IsEnabled` set to `False`, sets the `Background` to `new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(0xf4, 0xf4, 0xf4))` (or RGB 244,244,244), which is the grey you see. You can't change that.

What you can do is create a new control template for the button (yay), replacing the `Themes:ButtonChrome` element with a `Border` element, which you are able to change the `Background` of.

It may not appear to work in design view, but it works when you run it.

So, for instance, for yours, it might look something like:

```
<!-- Default button focus visual -->
<Style x:Key="ButtonFocusVisual">
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Rectangle Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource ButtonFocusVisual}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="MediumAquamarine"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="MediumBlue"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid>
                    <Border x:Name="Border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DeepPink"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 3):

Add `BasedOn` toolbar button style. This solution worked for me:

`BasedOn="{​StaticResource {​x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}​}​"`