# ToggleButton Style; Override IsEnabled

Tags: wpf

Once the ToggleButton is checked, the Button should be set to disabled and the foreground color should change. The following is not working:

```
      <Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <ToggleButton  Content="Hallo" Margin="113,97,72,46" >
        <ToggleButton.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="False"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
                    </Trigger>

                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ToggleButton.Style>
    </ToggleButton>

</Grid>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I pasted you code in Visual Studio and it worked

Comment: Did the foreground color changed to green?

Comment: No chance, the text color is default gray. Could you imagine why?

Comment: I don't know, does it work if you past that code in a new instance of visual studio?

Comment: No, also a restart of visual Studio did not work

Comment: Is this a desktop WPF application? Is there more XAML around?

Comment: no, just this surrounded by a grid and a window

Comment: Post all the xaml up from <Window>, are you using code behind?

Comment: I don't know, are you daltonic?

Comment: It works. But why are you using different triggers here? You could have the Setters for "IsEnabled" and "Foreground" both under <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">...

Answer (score 0):

The appearance of disabled controls is different across different versions of windows and different Windows account settings etc, this is why it's working for others but not you. Generally speaking you should respect such settings, but if you really are adamant then you'll need to explicitly override the template as demonstrated in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25406878/wpf-disabled-buttons-background):

```
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="MyContentPresenter" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```